# Set Image From Gallery or camera to fit into imagevew and make it zoom in zoom out

Tags: android, imageview, scaletype

I am new to Android.

I have a problem with setting image from gallery or camera to ImageView. I want to do a implement a Zoom functionality in ImageView.

I used [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/multi-touch-panning-pinch-zoom-image-view-in-android-using/) for zoom in/out or pinch. It works good, but image do not fit to ImageView's space by default.

When I use `ScaleType="CenterCrop"` it works, but Zoom functionality stops.

I want to :

1) Fit the picked image from gallery or Camera to ImageView by default.

2) Pinch gesture to zoom in/out.

3) Set minimum zoom to ImageView's height

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Achieve 1 using this library (https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage)
Achieve 2 and 3 using PhotoView (https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView).

It's an implementation of ImageView for Android that supports zooming, by various touch gestures.( 3 can be achieved by using `setMinimumScale(float minimumScale)`).
Hope this helps.

Comment: But How can i use 2 or more librery on single Imageview?

Comment: There's no problem with that. EasyImage library is just to get the source image from camera or from gallery. It doesn't care if you'll put it as a src to ImageView or any other widget. PhotoView will take care of gestures. They work together fine. It's not like they're both trying to do the same thing. There's no conflict.

Comment: And when i said to use PhotoView, i meant to use it instead of the implementation you provided in your question.